# Handling large xml documents

Tags: xml, oracle, binary, large-files, xmltype

I understand that xmltype stored as securefile binary xml can handle file sizes up to 4 GB.

I was wondering if anyone know any good ways to handle larger than 4 GB xml files, both storing in database and reading\selecting data from it.

Comment: I am not very familiar with xml, but I have considered looping through, fetching chunks of nodes within clobsize, and storing it in said chunks. But seeing as these files can get potentially BIG, this will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store such big XML-files as `XMLType` in Oracle database.

Most of XML-functions in Oracle are based on [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which requires to have the entire XML document loaded into memory including a huge amount of overhead data. Even on big machines this often causes memory leaks or similar problems.

In order to put such XML into database you should consider an external stream-based, resp. event-based XML parser, often called [SAX (Simple API for XML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). You have SAX parsers available at almost every programming language. The content of XML are then stored as usual relational data. Creating such big XML from Oracle database would be done "line-by-line" into a `CLOB`.

See also [PL/SQL APIs for XMLType](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb10pls.htm#ADXDB1100)

> This type of procedural processing is available through the SAX interface in the Oracle XDK Java and C components.

Typically you have to write more code when you use a SAX parser, because it does not provide any modification or query elements. In the meantime there are stream based parsers available (e.g. Perl [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm)) which are as powerful like a DOM based parser.

Comment: Do you have any citations that parsing XML causes memory leaks specifically in Oracle databases?

Comment: I found this one: [PL/SQL APIs for XMLType](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb10pls.htm#ADXDB1100): *Prior to Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1), each text node or attribute value processed by Oracle XML DB was limited in size to 64 K bytes. Starting with release 11.1, this restriction no longer applies.* It is quite some time ago when I developed my application, I assume this limit applied at that time. For sure the standard DOM based parsers did not work.

Comment: And this one: [XML Parsing for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK19112) *When a program parses a large XML document and creates a DOM tree in memory, it can affect performance.* And for older release: [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs): XML Parser for PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91773_01/ids902dl/web.902/a88894/adx28ppl.htm#1004621): *You should not be using the DOMParser for parsing a 50Mb XML file. You need to look at the SAXParser which parses files of arbitrary size because it does not create an in-memory tree of nodes as it goes.*